# Open a new window with the button

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I am building a real time monitoring project where information is given in the first window and that's keep on updating in the second window. I am trying to monitor the updated information in parallel from a different window using the same code, but as I pressed the new button and given the new information it is updating in the previous window also but I wanted *monitor window* to be completely different, so that I can monitor the different information in parallel using the same code. Please have a look at the sample code and help me with the ideas.

The sample code:

```
import time
import threading
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import queue
from tkinter import *

class Demo1:
    data=[]
    def __init__(self, master):#Python scrollbar on text widget
        self.master = master
        self.t=tkinter.Text(self.master,height=20,width=50)
        self.t.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.button = tkinter.Button(self.master,height=3,width=10, text="OK", command = self.new_window)
        self.button.grid(row=2,column=1)
    def new_window(self):
        self.inputValue=self.t.get("1.0",'end-1c')
        Demo1.data1=self.inputValue.split("\n")
        self.master.destroy() # close the current window
        self.master = tkinter.Toplevel() # create another Tk instance
        self.app = Demo2(self.master) # create Demo2 window
        self.master.mainloop()

        
class Demo2:
    t1 = []
    s1 = True
    display = []
    display1 = []
    i=0
    kas = True
    num=0
    j1=0
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.button = tkinter.Button(self.master,height=2,width=11, text="new",command=self.new).place(x=0,y=0)
        self.label = tkinter.Label(self.master, text="monitor", font=("Arial",20)).grid(row=0, columnspan=3)
        cols = ('aa','bb')
        self.listBox = ttk.Treeview(self.master, columns=cols)
        for col in cols:
            self.listBox.heading(col, text=col)
            self.listBox.column(col,minwidth=0,width=170)
        self.listBox.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.a()
    def a(self):
        self._img=tkinter.PhotoImage(file="green1.gif")
        a=Demo1.data1
        for i,(a) in enumerate(a): #here I have some function which runs repeatedlly  
            self.listBox.insert('', 'end',image=self._img, value=(a))
        threading.Timer(1.0, self.a).start()
    def new(self):
        main()

                            
def main():
    root = tkinter.Toplevel()
    app = Demo1(root)
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have given the ***pppp*** information to monitor but as a pressed new button and added the ***xx*** information its updating in the previous window also. Please help me with the idea so that the link between these window will be vanished.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have some major issues with your program. Including how you are trying to use your classes. The Toplevel() object was giving me issue, so I used Tk(). This should show you how to properly use the classes with the window. Most importantly your second window needs to be created from global not the first window. Also Demo1.data is a reference to your class definition not the actual data you loaded. I hope this example is helpful.

```py
from tkinter import *

 # your second window should be created in global
def create_demo2():
    global app, app2
    root2 = Tk()
    app2 = Demo2(root2, app)


class Demo1:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.data = ""
        self.button = Button(self.window, text="New Window",
                             command=create_demo2)
        self.button.pack()

    def set_data(self):
        self.data = "data"


class Demo2:
 # you could just use app from global scope, but I like to pass so that it is explicit.
    def __init__(self, window, app1): 
        self.window = window
        self.button_set = Button(self.window, text="Set", command=app1.set_data)
        self.button_use = Button(self.window, text="Use", command=self.use_data)
        self.app = app1
        self.label = Label(self.window)
        self.button_set.pack()
        self.button_use.pack()
        self.label.pack()

    def use_data(self):
        self.label.configure(text=self.app.data)


root = Tk()
app = Demo1(root)
app2 = None

root.mainloop()
```